Measure to Calculate Objective
Using DAX, I want to create a measure to calculate the level reached based on the amount of sales by the seller, month, product, and year. It searches the objectives table based on the seller, month, and year, then returns the corresponding level, considering that I have intermediate tables such as the calendar table and the table of seller name,I will use something like (if sales >= tier 1 & sales > tier 2, 1).
Below are examples of the tables.

